# How do I mount a (possibly encrypted) Mac-formatted Iomega zip disk under Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, zip-drive

I have a machine with an internal Iomega Zip-250 drive, running Debian stable (Lenny).  I have been using it to back up a pile of Zip-100 disks from back when they were popular.  Once I learned to mount them using `/dev/hdd4`, things mostly run smoothly.  Unfortunately, one of them refuses to mount.  Even worse, when I try to mount it, it sometimes deletes `/dev/hdd4` entirely, leaving the rest of the `/dev/hdd*` nodes alone:

```
eswald:~/backups/iomega> grep zipdrive /etc/fstab
/dev/hdd4       /media/zipdrive auto    noauto,user,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0
(exit 0) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> ls -l /dev/hdd?
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 65 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd1
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 66 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd2
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 67 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd3
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 68 2009-12-12 20:58 /dev/hdd4
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 69 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd5
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 70 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd6
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 71 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd7
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 72 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd8
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 73 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd9
(exit 0) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> mount -r /media/zipdrive
mount: special device /dev/hdd4 does not exist
(exit 1) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> ls -l /dev/hdd?
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 65 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd1
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 66 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd2
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 67 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd3
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 69 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd5
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 70 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd6
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 71 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd7
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 72 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd8
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 73 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd9
(exit 0) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> sudo mknod /dev/hdd4 b 22 68
[sudo] password for eswald:
(exit 0) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> mount -r /media/zipdrive
mount: /dev/hdd4 is not a valid block device
(exit 1) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega> ls -l /dev/hdd?
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 65 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd1
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 66 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd2
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 67 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd3
brw-r--r-- 1 root root   22, 68 2009-12-12 21:23 /dev/hdd4
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 69 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd5
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 70 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd6
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 71 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd7
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 72 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd8
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 22, 73 2009-12-12 11:05 /dev/hdd9
(exit 0) (0 jobs)
eswald:~/backups/iomega>
```

Similar things error messages happen without `-r`.  A previous use of the `mknod` command listed has worked before to mount another zip disk, after it was deleted while mounting this one; any successful mount resets the permissions and group to look like the other hdd nodes.

Trying to mount it also results in some error messages in `/var/log/messages`:

```
[1162348.230836] hdd: 98304kB, 196608 blocks, 512 sector size
[1162348.232342] hdd: 98304kB, 96/64/32 CHS, 4096 kBps, 512 sector size, 2941 rpm
[1162348.527145]  hdd:<3>ide-floppy: hdd: I/O error, pc = 28, key =  7, asc = 30, ascq = 80
[1162348.640697] Dev hdd: unable to read RDB block 0
[1162348.706355]  unable to read partition table
```

This particular disk was used on Macintosh System 7 machines, in 1997-1998, and was probably initialized with a Macintosh file system.  HFS is listed in `/proc/filesystems`, and I am willing to install other file systems on suggestion.  However, I seem to recall having used Iomega's encryption facilities for this disk; if so, I probably still remember the password, but I need to find a way to use it.

Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the Macintosh machines on which I originally used it, nor any others with zip drives.

Comment: if you used an encryption facility, even one present in "standard" HFS, it is highly unlikely you'll find an open-source HFS driver that will support it.  your best bet may be to find an old Mac and Zip-250 drive for it.

Comment: It might just be password-protected, instead of encryped.

Comment: wow, a working zip drive

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of searching, and something that turns up is jaztool. It used to be packaged in
debian, the source seems to available from http://archive.debian.net/en/source/slink/jaztool.
You could try compiling it on your machine. Good luck!

Comment: The documentation makes it look perfect, but running it gives me `jaztool: not a raw scsi device`.  Do I need a newer Linux version, or is it just incompatible with an internal IDE zip drive?

Comment: More likely you need an older version of Linux. (You did compile it? The scsi interfaces were notorious for breaking binary compatibility). Perhaps it just wants another device name.

Comment: It is looking for a /dev/sdX format for the device. Potentially this could be changed in the code.

Comment: @eswald Posted the source code of `jaztool` that I found in OS archives here: https://github.com/cengique/jaztool . I made a couple of updates to get the USB model of the ZIP 250 drive.